# Why does adding 1 to numeric_limits<float>::min() return 1?

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, x86-64, floating-accuracy

How come subtracting 1 from float max returns a sensible value, but adding 1 to float min returns 1?

I thought that if you added or subtracted a value smaller than the epsilon for that particular magnitude, then nothing would happen and there would be no increase or decrease.

Here is the code I compiled with g++ with no flags and ran on x86_64.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float min = std::numeric_limits<float>::min() + 1;
    float max = std::numeric_limits<float>::max() - 1;

    std::cout << min << std::endl << max << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs this:

```
1
3.40282e+38
```

I would expect it to output this:

```
-3.40282e+38
 3.40282e+38
```

Comment: What would you expect from 1.0 + 0.000000000000000001?

Comment: You're not even printing the output exactly, with hex-float format or extra decimal digits.  But IIRC, the min normalized float is below FLT_EPSILON, so the result is *exactly* 1.0, lost to rounding error.

Comment: *I thought that if you added or subtracted a value smaller than the epsilon for that particular magnitude, then nothing would happen and there would be no increase or decrease.* Yep.  1 + something_to_small = 1

Comment: I actually saw that std::numeric_limits::lowest produces more sensible results. But why does it work for max and not min? Isn't there symmetry?

And I would still expect there to be no change, rather than jumping all the way up to 1.

Comment: @AdrianMole I would expect 1.0 + 0.000000000000000001 to equal 1.

But that doesn't help me understand why 1.17549e-38 + 1 is equal to 1

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what [std::numeric_limits<float>::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) is.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` is the lowest *magnitude* normalized `float`, not `-max`.

Comment: @silverscania `1.17549e-38` is `.000000000000000000000000000000000000011754` (may have more or less zeros).  Why don't you think that is the same?

Comment: Oh yes I get it now, 1.17549e-38 is not a hugely negative number, its just a very small number close to 0.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Yeah I get it now. I just saw the - sign in the output, and combined with what min() does for other types, and jumped to the conclusion that it was a negative value.

I understand that 1.17549e-38 is a small positive value, I just misread it.

Comment: @PeterCordes isn't the lowest magnitude normalised float 0? Or does the word normalised add in something extra that means it can't be 0.

Comment: @silverscania: Technically `0.0` is a subnormal: its exponent field is all-0, so the implied leading bit of the mantissa is 0, not 1.

Comment: I edited the expected output to show that I was confused that min() isn't a negative value.

@PeterCordes I suppose I still don't understand why min() couldn't have been either 0 or negative max() when epsilon() and denorm_min() exist to provide that functionality.

But I suppose that is an issue with the API design, not the original question

Comment: @silverscania: Did you see the answer I just posted?  `denorm_min()` is a different number, and like `lowest` only appeared in C++11.  `epsilon` is also larger than `min`; the dynamic range of `float` is wider than the precision of a single float.  `FLT_EPSILON` tells you about the precision (mantissa bits), `FLT_MIN` tells you about how many exponent bits.  Along with `FLT_MAX`, those are the 3 most important constants, which C has historically had in `float.h`.

Comment: Yeah I just read through it after I posted that question. Thanks for explaining

Comment: In C without templates, you always know when you're writing FP code, so you can use `-FLT_MAX` as appropriate.  Having more bloated headers to define negative versions of all these constants would make compilation slower.  (Remember C is old, keeping implementations compact used to matter before we had boatloads of RAM, disk, and CPU time.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` returns the smallest normalized positive value. To get the value that has no value lower than it, use `std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min

Comment: Do you know why that was picked to be the value for min() rather than the lowest negative value?

Seems to be an outlier with regards to all the other types.

Comment: I am no historian. Just a dude who wields cppreference.com against the tides of confusion.

Comment: @BessieTheCow: My bad, I was mixing up `lowest` with smallest subnormal ("lowest *positive* value that has no *positive* value lower than it).  This answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

**[`min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) is the smallest-magnitude positive normalized float, a very tiny positive number (about `1.17549e-38`), not a negative number with large magnitude**.  Notice that the `-` is in the exponent, and this is scientific notation.  `e-38` means 38 zeros after the decimal point.  Try it out on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to play with the bits in a binary `float`.

`std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` is the minimum *magnitude* normalized `float`, not `-max`.  [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) even has a note about this possibly being surprising.

> Do you know why that was picked to be the value for min() rather than the lowest negative value? Seems to be an outlier with regards to all the other types.

Some of the sophistication in [`numeric_limits<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) like `lowest` and `denorm_min` is new in C++11.  Most of the choice of what to define mostly followed C.  Historical C valued economy and didn't define a lot of different names.  (Smaller is better on ancient computers, and also less stuff in the global namespace which is all C had access to.)

Float types are normally<sup>1</sup> symmetric around 0 (sign/magnitude representation), so C didn't have a separate named constant for the most-negative float / double / long double.  Just `FLT_MAX` and `FLT_MIN` CPP macros.  C doesn't have templates, so you know when you're writing FP code and can use a `-` on the appropriate constant if necessary.

**If you're only going to have a few named constants, the three most interesting ones are:**

- `FLT_EPSILON` tells you about the available precision (mantissa bits): `nextafter(1.0, +INF) - 1.0`
- `FLT_MIN` / `FLT_MAX` min (normalized) and max magnitudes of finite floats.  This depends mostly on how many exponent bits a float has.

  They're not quite symmetric around 1.0 for 2 reasons: all-ones mantissa in FLT_MAX, and gradual underflow (subnormals) taking up the lowest exponent-field (0 with bias), but `FLT_MIN` ignoring subnormals.  `FLT_MIN * FLT_MAX` is about 3.99999976 for [IEEE754 binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) `float`.  (You normally want to avoid subnormals for performance reasons, and so you have room for gradual underflow, so it makes sense that FLT_MIN isn't `denorm_min`)

(Fun fact: `0.0` is a special case of a subnormal: exponent field = 0 implying a mantissa of 0.xxx instead of 1.xxx).

**Footnote 1:** CppReference points out that C++11 [`std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest) *could* be different from `-max` for 3rd-party FP types, but isn't for standard C++ FP types.

`lowest` *is* what you wanted: the most-negative finite value.  It's consistent across integer and FP types as being the most-negative value, so for example you could use it as an initializer for a templated search loop that uses `std::min` to find the lowest value in an array.

C++11 also introduced [`denorm_min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/denorm_min), the minimum positive subnormal aka denormal value for FP types.  In IEEE754, the object representation has all bits 0 except for a 1 in the low bit of the mantissa.

---

**The float result for `1.0 + 1.17549e-38` (after rounding to the nearest `float`) is exactly `1.0`.**  `min` is lower than `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon` so the entire change is lost to rounding error when added to `1.0`.

So even if you did print the float with full precision (or as a hex float), it would be `1.0`.  But you're just printing with the default formatting for `cout` which rounds to some limited precision, like 6 decimal digits.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

(An earlier version of the question included the numeric value of `min` ~= 1.17549e-38; this answer started out addressing that mixup and I haven't bothered to fully rewrite those parts).

Comment: Detail: "`FLT_MAX` ... max magnitudes of normalized finite floats." is slightly amiss.  `FLT_MAX` is specified as the max finite `float` without _normalized_.  Only select FP encodings (like [double/double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic)) have a different max normal and max denormal so it often does not make a difference.  Perhaps later [C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2316.htm#dr_467) will change things.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Interesting point; adjusted wording to still be technically correct.  Your comment is sufficient mention of the reason, though; my answer is cluttered enough.  And I'm not very familiar with double-double; I didn't know in the first place that it could do denormalized gradual overflow .